# Python groupby multiple columns and transform pandas key error

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, transform

I'm having some trouble applying a transform to a 2 column groupby in Pandas. I've tried a number of things referencing similar use cases.

I'm looking to groupby by date and user and do a transform on a flag column by saying if 'nan' then 0 else 1. My data looks like this:

```
    user     date        Flag
0    ron  12/21/2019      1 
1    ron  12/22/2019      2  
2  april   12/21/2016    nan  
3  april  12/23/2016      1  
4   andy   12/21/2016    nan
```

Here's what I've setup, which logically makes sense to me but I get a keyerror.

```
s = master['Flag'].eq('nan').groupby(master['date','user']).transform('any')
master.loc[:,'attendance'] = s.map({True:0,False: 1})
```

```
KeyError: ('date', 'user')
```

Comment: `[['date', 'user']]`rather than `['date', 'user']`:)

Comment: i did try that but was getting a different error - ```ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `master['Flag'].eq('nan')` you have just Series type. Then you call `.groupby` and should pass columns for grouping (but there is no such columns there).

If i have correctly understood whole task, here is the code:

```
# step 1
master['Flag'] = master['Flag'] == 'nan'
master

Out[1]:

    user    date        Flag
0   ron     12/21/2019  False
1   ron     12/22/2019  False
2   april   12/21/2016  True
3   april   12/23/2016  False
4   andy    12/21/2016  True

# step 2

s = master.groupby(['date','user']).agg('any')
s

Out[2]:

                    Flag
    date    user    
12/21/2016  andy    True
            april   True
12/21/2019  ron     False
12/22/2019  ron     False
12/23/2016  april   False


# step 3

s['attendance'] = s['Flag'].map({True:0,False: 1})
s

Out[3]:

                    Flag    attendance
    date    user        
12/21/2016  andy    True    0
            april   True    0
12/21/2019  ron     False   1
12/22/2019  ron     False   1
12/23/2016  april   False   1
```

### ..or short version

```
master.assign(flg = master['Flag'] == 'nan').groupby(['date','user'])[['flg']].agg('any')['flg'].map({True:0,False: 1}).to_frame()
```

Comment: thank you very much this works for me! in the short version, what does the to_frame piece do?

Comment: It convert the series (in last step it has only one column, so it processed like series) to dataframe.